# Extra fields in user_role / roles tables or a new table

Tags: database-design, performance, query-performance

I have a user_roles table which I use to manage permissions and user's access to certain things. For example, a team manager is a role. Since a team manager belongs to a specific team, the way I handle that is by having extra fields in these tables for example:

```
roles_table
  * has_record
  * record_str

user_roles_table
  * record_id
```

So if I need to get the team of a team manager, I would have to check the roles record to get the record_str, in this case 'Team' and instantiate an object using that string and the record id in user_roles.

I did it this way because it was a generic way to apply it across all roles in which case I can continue to add roles without changes. Its also nice for adding roles to users. If I am assigning roles, and it has a record, I can then query for the records using the str and display the options in a drop down.

My concern with this is the performance. Do you guys think it will last at a high scale?

The other option I was considering was to just create a table for each user role. This is less modular since if I want to create a role I need add a table, but it provides a more direct way of getting from the user_role to the record without all the joins in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use your current design over creating a table for each user role. Why create a new role, when your code may have to cycle through several tables to get an answer that could have come from one place.  (Opinion:  You would just be making more work for yourself.)

Of course, a Team, a TeamManager, and a TeamMember may all have some attributes that are related only to their individual roles.

If you are facing that challenge, then a supertype-subtype design can work well for this issue.  All the common data is in the supertype table, but each subtype contains data unique to that role/task/etc.  (Whatever you are trying to manage.)

A Microsoft Tutorial give a basic description at **Lesson 5: Supertypes and Subtypes** at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505839.aspx

Comment: So are you basically suggesting that I keep my current design, and for roles that need more specific attributes I can create a new table?

Comment: Yes, the simple design seems flexible enough, but will naturally get augmented as you work out other requirements. Performance can become a problem, but a SQL Server (even the free version) can handle a lot of data quickly.  So I would not worry about the number of rows of data unless you have a massive database.  Performance will also benefit from good relational design, efficient coding, and the needed indexes.

Comment: I guess my last question is then, for role checking should I be sticking to one method or can I mix and match? What I mean is, based on my design above traditionally I would have to check roles like so. `select user_id from user_roles where role_id = (select id from roles where role = ROLE_NAME);` but assuming some roles with have their own tables, it would be easier to do `select user_id from ROLE_TABLE_NAME;` is there any thing wrong with this approach?

Comment: The more you can handle role checking in a single place, the simpler the process will be.  There may be some cases that data needs to be obtained from another table, but I would design to minimize the possibility..